# Word for "observing something with the purpose of gaining knowledge from it"?

Tags: single-word-requests

And for a long period of time.

Example:

> He spent several nights [...] the terrorist's building.

I checked the synonyms of *watch* (noun lookout), but found nothing that could fit. There's also *track*, but I think it implies walking:

> [track](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=track%20define&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=2TNTVdKgMZTd8AXG4oDQCw)
>   follow the trail or movements of (someone or something), typically in
>   order to find them or note their course.

Maybe to *keep vigil*?

Comment: *Studying*, perhaps?

Comment: @StoneyB *Studying a building*? I think it doesn't fit very well.

Comment: *Monitoring, surveying*, or your very own *observing*.

Comment: "Surveilling" is the word used in all the cop shows.

Comment: @janoChen: You certainly *can* study a building. You can study the back of your hand, for that matter. Or anything else.

Comment: @Robusto I see. OK. I'll consider it then.

Comment: In support of @StoneyB's comment: See [14 Famous Figures Every Architecture Student Should Study](http://www.careeroverview.com/blog/2010/14-famous-figures-every-architecture-student-should-study/) which is all about architecture students studying buildings.

Comment: What is "it" in the title? The observing, or the thing observed? I edited the title to say "about it" and Robusto changed it back to "from it".  I took it to be "the thing observed" and apparently he takes "it" to be the observing.

Comment: @StoneyB The problem with "study" is that it doesn't necessarily imply going to the building and seeing what happens there. It could just mean staring at the plans.

Comment: @StoneyB:  Study is definitely the way to go; the other options do not reference the purpose of gaining knowledge.  The sample text is a poor match for the question, unless the speaker intends to learn how to be a better terrorist or construct buildings for terrorists.

Comment: @janoChen: "Track" does not imply walking.  To track something is to monitor or observe it as it passes through time and/or space.  You can track a bear through the woods (walking), track a satellite's orbit around Earth (standing), or track an idea through history (reading).  "Trace" is a common synonymy in this regard.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If informal usage would work for you you could use:

[stake out](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stake) as a verb:

> they’d staked out Culley’s flat for a day (ODO)
>
> He spent several nights **staking out** the terrorist's building.

Answer (score 13):

Surveilling:
verb (transitive) 
1. to observe closely the activities of (a person or group)

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/surveilling?s=t

Answer (score 12):

The act of checking out a location, particularly in the context of the military, is called ***[reconnoitering](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reconnoiter)***. One can also make a ***reconnaisance*** of a place, like before attempting to occupy it. (M-W)

Comment: I am reminded that Garrison Keillor, in a rare slip of the tongue, used "reconnoiter" when he meant "rendezvous" in one of his Writers' Almanac segments.

Comment: lol @HotLicks even professional writers could get confused, I guess.

Answer (score 9):

> *He spent several nights* [casing](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/case#case-2__18) *the terrorist's building.*

Appropriate if the surveillance is done in anticipation of a crime, especially a robbery.  Also applies specifically to places or locations, not people nor things therein.  (For example, you case a bank, but not a bank manager nor a bank safe.)

From [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/case):

> to study or watch (a house, store, etc.) with plans to rob it

From [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/case#case-2__18):

> *informal* Reconnoitre (a place) before carrying out a robbery

Comment: Using of law enforcement reconnoitering a criminal establishment is decent play on words, especially if building a broader ironic metaphor. +1

Answer (score 8):

Most of the good words are taken.

One isn't:

**studying** [[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/study): verb, sense 2]

> to watch or to look at somebody/something carefully in order to find out something

Comment: I'm not sure this quite works. "Studying" could just mean staring at the plans, whereas the question seems to involve looking at the actual building.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: If you stare at the plans, you're studying the plans. If you stare at the building, you're studying the building. Anyway, I thought of the answer based on  the title.

Comment: But if you stare at the plans, you're also studying the building. My point is that "studying the building" includes the possibility of not going anywhere near it, just as "The historian studies King Louis XIV" doesn't mean "She goes and looks at some dead guy's corpse."

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Now you're being intentionally funny. There are two senses of `study`. The sense I think is applicable, I've quoted. Your latest example likely uses study in sense 1. There are lots of words with multiple senses and it's easy to split hairs arguing that it would mean something else if you see it my way.

Comment: No, I'm not being funny. If you say to somebody "I studied the building", they may misunderstand you; if you say "I reconnoitred/surveilled/staked out the building", they will not misunderstand you. Why would you want to use a word that could be misunderstood when there are plenty of words available that would not be misunderstood? The "study the plans" misinterpretation is very plausible: we've all seen movies where the good/bad guys study the plans of a building before assaulting it.

Comment: That's why I started the answer with "good words are taken". Study is maybe a bit ambiguous here, but there are plenty of situations where it won't be. And it's a perfectly fine word to use _if you just read the title_. "He studied her face thoughtfully."

Comment: Please don't pretend that the title is the whole question. The body of the question gives context that makes it clear that somebody's face is not the object of interest.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: And Louis's Corpse is?

Comment: @DavidRicherby: The body of the question states it's an EXAMPLE.

Answer (score 7):

He spent several nights *surveying* the terrorist's building? Perhaps 'analyzing'?

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/study might help inspire you!

Comment: "Surveying" implies being there with a [surveyor's transit and stick](http://www.oocities.org/trainhead391/survpic01.JPG).

Comment: Not really: verb (used with object)
1.
to take a general or comprehensive view of or appraise, as a situation, area of study, etc.
2.
to view in detail, especially to inspect, examine, or appraise formally or officially in order to ascertain condition, value, etc.

Comment: I'm just saying what the reader will read.

Comment: @HotLicks I agree that it sounds like the job of surveying in this context because of _building_, but I think the _appraisal_ definition is more widely used and known.

Answer (score 4):

To ***[scrutinize](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scrutinize)*** may be another option:

> - to examine or observe with great care; inspect critically.
> - to examine carefully or in minute detail.

The Free Dictionary

Comment: 'Scrutinize' to some extent implies close proximity to me, though.

Answer (score 4):

### To "monitor" is to continuously observe a defined subject

To "monitor" has for me the strongest implication of continuous attention regarding new knowledge to gain.
In the example, it is about collecting all relevant information, not to work with the infromation instead, which would draw attention from collecting.

So studying it, and investigating - all that comes later, based on the result of monitoring.

Answer (score 2):

How about [Spying](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spying)

```
One who secretly collects information concerning the enemies of a government or group
```

Apart from the information collection being done secretly, I believe this word would fit in your requirement.

Comment: Spying has rather negative connotations but it does accurately describe the situation.

Answer (score 2):

[**Scouting**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scouting?s=t) was what came to mind immediately for me.

> He spent several nights scouting the terrorist's building.

Answer (score 1):

[Sizing up](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/size+up) sounds best to me although slightly colloquial:

He spent several nights sizing up the terrorist's building.

or more formally [evaluating](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/evaluating) at the risk of losing some of the flavour:

He spent several nights evaluating the terrorist's building.

Answer (score 1):

**grok**

verb \ˈgräk\

grokked grok·king

Definition of GROK:

> transitive verb: to understand profoundly and intuitively

Examples of GROK

> *the eternal struggle of the human race to grok its place in the grand scheme of the universe*

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-)! This is a great word, although I'm not sure that the OP had intuition in mind. Your answer would be even better if you referenced the dictionary the definition is from (you can [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/246164/edit) your post to do that) , but for a first answer it is quite a nice one :-).

Comment: This doesn't work. To "grok" is to understand but the question asks for a verb that means to acquire information. You could say that, after staking out the building, he grokked the terrorists' behaviour but that's one stage beyond what's being asked for.

Answer (score -1):

*Combing through* is an expression that fits your example well.

Comment: "Comb the desert!"

Comment: No. To comb through something is to search it carefully. This doesn't apply to the situation described in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Auditing, like auditing a college course

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Mark! I'd say this is a pretty close word for it, but [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/audit) says _audit_ is more of a review and not an intake of something. Also, be sure to elaborate on your answer to help everyone out.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Mark. There are several things you could do to [improve](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) your answer.

Answer (score -1):

The most reliable **knowledge** is that acquired by the [scientific method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method).

> Four essential elements of the scientific method are iterations,
>   recursions, inter-leavings, or orderings of the following:
>
> - Characterizations (observations, definitions, and measurements of the subject of inquiry)
> - Hypotheses (theoretical, hypothetical explanations of observations and measurements of the subject)
> - Predictions (reasoning including logical deduction from the hypothesis or theory)
> - Experiments (tests of all of the above)
>     <sub>[Wikipedia: Elements of the Scientific Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method)</sub>

So to gain knowledge scientists need to **characterize** the subject of inquiry.  One possible term for this process might be "**data collection**" but you'll be hard pressed to find a better term than your own, as @RegDwigнt already commented

> **observe**
>
> *transitive verb*
>
> - 1.a. To be or become aware of, especially through careful and directed attention; *notice: observed a car leaving the property.*
> - 1.b. To watch attentively: *observe a child's behavior.*
> - 1.c. To make a systematic or scientific observation of: *observe the orbit of a comet.*
>     <sub>[TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/observe)</sub>

A great example of making **observations** over a long period of time was

> **Tycho Brahe**, born Tyge Ottesen Brahe (14 December 1546 – 24 October 1601), was a Danish nobleman known for his accurate and
>   comprehensive astronomical and planetary **observations**. He was born in
>   Scania, then part of Denmark, now part of modern-day Sweden. Tycho was
>   well known in his lifetime as an astronomer, astrologer and alchemist,
>   and has been described more recently as "*the first competent mind in
>   modern astronomy to feel ardently the passion for exact empirical
>   facts.*"
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tycho_Brahe#Career:_observing_the_heavens)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

"peruse" - IMHO the best word possible to mean, “observing something with the purpose of gaining knowledge from it”.  Although "examine" is pretty near exactly the same.

Comment: "Peruse" has a strong connotation, if not denotation, of superficially examining something for the purpose of amusement.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Superficially? [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/peruse) disagrees:"peruse:  Examine carefully or at length:" How well it fits (or does not fit) the OP's needs might be a subject for discussion, but it is a legitimate answer. Milo, welcome to the ELU :-). You could prevent disagreement with your answer if you [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/246124/edit) your post to include references.